# Feature - Show the last 10 questions viewed and the activity of them

Tags: feature-request

<strike>Show the last 10 question that I had read, answered recently....</strike>

Comments no, because there's already the "notifier"...

There are times when I read the question, it looks interesting and I want to be notified if it was answered. Mark the question as favorite it's ok, but it's difficult to "reach" the tab favorite since it is in the users profile....

I don't know, something in the sidebar or in the "notifier", keeping me updated about the answers of a question, not just the comments....

Thanks

EDIT*** after @Arjan Comments...

In the sidebar show the last 10 questions viewed and in the box that appears in the top menu when you hover your name the activity of the last 10 questions I viewed.

Comment: With the API you could create a browser extension to do that.

Comment: I just checked the new entry in the blog http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/stack-exchange-api-usage-stats-and-api-2-0-plans/ and there are a lot of applications that uses the API and it does this 'feature' and more of I was proposing. Well anyways...I'll check some of those apps...thanks!

Comment: Do not understand the dowvote....anyway.... I think the title must be Show the last 10 viewed questions.....

Comment: Please edit a bit more: to me the first paragraph suggests you're only asking for a list of the last 10 questions you visited, but the remaining part seems to ask for notifications for those questions as well? (And while editing, please drop the dots from the text, and the semi-tag from the title. Thanks!)

Comment: So, are you asking: *Show activity of the last 10 questions I viewed*?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say....In a sidebar the last 10 questions viewed and in the box that appears in the top menu when you hover your name the activity of the last 10 questions I viewed

Answer (score 1):

> Show the last 10 question that I had read, answered recently....
>
> Comments no, because there's already the "notifier"...

[image: You can easily select stuff in the activity tab.]

> There are times when I read the question, it looks interesting and I want to be notified if it was answered. Mark the question as favorite it's ok, but it's difficult to "reach" the tab favorite since it is in the users profile....

[image: Just click on the link in the user popup.]

> I don't know, something in the sidebar or in the "notifier", keeping me updated about the answers of a question, not just the comments....

[image: That also works for favorites!]

There is notification about changes on favorite questions, but I'm not sure what that one covers.

Comment: But What I want is to keep track of some questions where I didn't make any activity, just read the question, (no comment, no answer, no editing,nothing) just read it (I don't want to keep track of all the questions I read, just a temporal place where I can see my last 10 questions that I read)....

And there could be another option that can keep me informed about a singular question that I marked as favorite or any other option...

Comment: Isn't that just how many favorites you added?

Comment: @agf: Is that better?

Comment: Lol. I thought you were just talking about the listing in the drop down, not on the `favorites` tab, since you could have indicated that the way you indicated the `activity` tab rather than indirectly through the drop-down.